# Ошибка верификации сертификата

Tags: php, ssl

При запросе к некоторым сайтем через fopen() или через curl возникают ошибки типа

> fopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
>   error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate
>   verify failed

или

> cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer
>   certificate

При том когда я перехожу на этот домен в браузере то с сертификатом все ок

Comment: Вопрос то в чем? почему в браузере ошибки нет а в curl есть - потому что в вашем браузере есть корневые сертификаты которым он доверяет, и в браузере\системе - могут быть разные корневые. curl доверяет только тем которые есть в системе(или которые вы ему дополнительно подсунете).

Answer (score 0):

Для curl можно просто отключить проверку, это не рекомендуется, но так многие делают:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

А по хорошему нужно указать путь к сертификату в `php.ini`:

```
curl.cainfo="/path/to/cacert.pem" # Путь только указать настоящий
```

Скачать сам сертификат можно с сайта - https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

Comment: Решение костыльное, надо скачивать корневой и проверять сертификат по цепочке, а не сравнивать со скачанным с сайта сертификатом

Answer (score -1):

вот эту строчку добавьте в код

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

И вы не будете проверять сертификат

Comment: Мне как раз надо проверить